# youtube api thumbnail doesn't change on video change (js)

Tags: api, youtube, thumbnails

I'm not sure where should i call the "get thumbnail" thing.
Right now i called it inside the:

```
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        timestamp_callback();
    }
    switch(event.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:

        // get video title
        // get video date
        // get video thumbnail
```

"is playing" part, since i also parsed video title, and other infos in there and it works, it also change when changing video, but thumbnails change only for some videos.

anyway this is the function i'm using inside the above **onPlayerStateChange(event)**:

```
// get video thumbnail
            $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=" + curvideID + "&key=" + ytApiKey, function(data) {
              var snip = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails;
              quality = snip.maxres.url;
              if (quality) {
                bgThumb.src = quality;
                bgThumb.style.setProperty("display", "block");
              }else{
                quality = snip.standard.url;
                if (quality) {
                  bgThumb.src = quality;
                  bgThumb.style.setProperty("display", "block");
                }else{
                  quality = snip.high.url;
                  if (quality) {
                    bgThumb.src = quality;
                    bgThumb.style.setProperty("display", "block");
                  }else{
                    quality = snip.medium.url;
                    if (quality) {
                      bgThumb.src = quality;
                      bgThumb.style.setProperty("display", "block");
                    }else{
                      quality = snip.default.url;
                      if (quality) {
                        bgThumb.src = quality;
                        bgThumb.style.setProperty("display", "block");
                      }else{
                      bgThumb.style.setProperty("display", "none");
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            });
```

please don't mind to the questionable if sequence, i'm sure there are shorter ways to do it but that was the way i figured to check for max res available for the video playing (unless that is the reason of my failure).

**UPDATE:** I found out that the call of the function is in the right place, there's something wrong with the if chain, in fact it only try the first one, if the video doesn't match that resolution the "if chain" doesn't go downward so it simply doesn't show anything.